Show/Hide HTML list items based on ajax results
I'm running a PHP file that uses javascript to add to a list of items that is pulled from a sql database. The search filter does not affect the items that were taken from the sql database. How can I get the sql items added to the ul so that it properly gets filtered?
Index.php, the html that has the "hardwired" items- items 1 and 2
<section>
    <h2>Item Selection</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="itemSearch" placeholder="Search for items">
    </form>
    <ul id="itemList">
        <li>
            <span>Item 1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Item 2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

Index.php, php code that adds the items from sql to the ul
fetch('get_data.php')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    const itemList = document.getElementById('itemList');
    data.forEach(item => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = "<span></span>";
        li.querySelector('span').textContent = item['ItemName'];
        itemList.appendChild(li);
    });

Index.php, js code that filters the list
const itemList = document.getElementById('itemList');
const items = itemList.querySelectorAll('li'); 
const itemSearchInput = document.getElementById('itemSearch');

// Filter item list based on search input
itemSearchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const searchQuery = itemSearchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    items.forEach(item => {
        const itemName = item.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (itemName.includes(searchQuery)) {
            item.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            item.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});


I think it has something to do with the onload() function, but I tried a bunch of versions and still haven't gotten it to work.

Move the declaration of items inside the event listener function, so it will get the current list of items that were added by the AJAX code.

Yeah, I'm re-reading this now and @Barmar is right. You aren't "doing something after PHP", you are "doing something after a JavaScript fetch". The fact that the fetch is accessing a PHP is unrelated to the problem

@Barmar that seems to have worked, if you make an answer, I'll confirm it. Also, why does that work- only moving the items declaration and not with the itemList declaration?

Reason: the querySelectorAll() method returns all elements that match a CSS selector(s) , so each time it is called it will get the latest data (if no scope is specified, it applies to the whole document)

Move items into the listener function, so it always gets the current set of items, rather than the items that were on the page when it first loaded (which is an empty list, since they're added dynamically).


const itemList = document.getElementById('itemList');
const itemSearchInput = document.getElementById('itemSearch');

// Filter item list based on search input
itemSearchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const items = itemList.querySelectorAll('li');
  const searchQuery = itemSearchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  items.forEach(item => {
    const itemName = item.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (itemName.includes(searchQuery)) {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});



